# Select current dropdown value - WordPress theme options

Tags: php, wordpress, drop-down-menu

Instead of only the current value being selected, they all are selected. When I echo the current value, it displays correctly, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to be selected.

```
<?php
echo $settings['featured-one'];
$cats = get_categories();
echo '<select name="sa_options[featured-one]"><option value="select">Select</option><option value="empty">Categories</option>';
foreach($cats as $cat){
    if ($cat->term_id.$cat->slug == $settings['featured-one']) $selected = 'selected="selected"';
    echo '<option value="'.$cat->term_id.$cat->slug.'" '.$selected.'> - '.$cat->name.'</option>';   
}
$pgs = get_pages();
echo '<option value="empty">Pages</option>';
foreach($pgs as $pg){
    if ($pg->ID.$pg->post_name == $settings['featured-one']) $selected = 'selected="selected"';
    echo '<option value="'.$pg->ID.$pg->post_name.'" '.$selected.'> - '.$pg->post_title.'</option>';
}
$posts = get_posts();
echo '<option value="empty">Posts</option>';
foreach($posts as $post){
    if ($post->ID.$post->post_name == $settings['featured-one']) $selected = 'selected="selected"';
    echo '<option value="'.$post->ID.$post->post_name.'" '.$selected.'> - '.$post->post_title.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: Inspect element & check is it getting `selected=selected` ?

Comment: Each option is getting the selected=selected.

Comment: Got your issue. Define `$selected = '';` before every if condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the above comment, I placed `$selected = '';` before every if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try WordPress default technique instead our own

refere link [selected function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected)

```
<!-- Testing the values with if() -->
<select name="options[foo]">
    <option value="1" <?php if ( $options['foo'] == 1 ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>1</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if ( $options['foo'] == 2 ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>2</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if ( $options['foo'] == 3 ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>3</option>
</select>

<!-- Using selected() instead -->
<select name="options[foo]">
    <option value="1" <?php selected( $options['foo'], 1 ); ?>>1</option>
    <option value="2" <?php selected( $options['foo'], 2 ); ?>>2</option>
    <option value="3" <?php selected( $options['foo'], 3 ); ?>>3</option>
</select>
```